# How to retrieve Array values in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, for-loop

In my Java Application i'm getting Request parameter like Array

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var names = new Array();
    $.ajax({
        url : "Result",
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            "names" : JSON.stringify(names),
            "globalClassId" : globalClassId
        }});
</script>
```

Now i'm getting this request parameter in java and retrieve the values correctly..

```
//Get the each added user using names[]
    for (String id : names) {
        -----
                    -----
    }
```

But in java side i'm getting values `names=[["1000"]]` and in for loop i'm getting `id=["value1"]`

if we pass this value to database for example select query,But it is giving null value.. even we pass correct value but we are getting null value.

How to remove this extra brackets in my String `["1000"]` this is original value but i want only `1000`.

Please help me is their any wrong declaration in Array.

Comment: Use a JSON library to parse your JSON input. You have GSon, Jackson and the common library from [json.org](http://www.json.org/java/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

use [**org.json**](http://www.json.org/java/)

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(request.getParameter("names"));


List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("interests");
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just i'm using String concept to solve this Problem but this is not real solution..

```
//Get the each added user using names[]
    for (String id : names) {
        userVO = userService.getUser(id.substring(2, id.length()-2));
        userList.add(userVO);
    }
```

If any body know real solution Please tell me...

Answer (score 1):

instead of `JSON.stringify(names)` we can use names.join() this will be return Array,

so we can easily send request attribute like string `@RequestParam("names") String names`

and now using for loop we easily get values like..

```
//Get the each added user using names[]
    for (String id : names.split(",")) {
        ----------
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing i want to tell you that generate your JSON like a list or Map Structure so that you can get Structure using any JSON or GSON Api.

It will make simple for you to retrieve them & no other Constraints needed in future to retrieve them.