# how to avoid Special characters to Create Json object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

In my Java script I'm create array and now I'm converting to `Json Object` using `stringify` method.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var array1 = new Array();
    $.ajax({
        url : "Result",
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            "array1" : JSON.stringify(array1),
            "globalClassId" : globalClassId
        }});
</script>
```

But in server side `array1` parameter creating like `["1","2","3"]` But we don't want extra bracket `[]`

How to Remove this extra bracket?

If we remove this extra `[]` the code look like `"1","2","3"` ,
we can simple loop it.

Comment: didn't you just asked the same question a while ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646724/how-to-retrieve-array-values-in-java

Comment: Try `array1.join()` instead of `JSON.stringify(array1)`

Answer (score 0):

Following code working for me..

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
       var array1 = new Array();
        $.ajax({
            url : "Result",
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                "array1" : array1.join(),
                "globalClassId" : globalClassId
            }});
    </script>
```

Comment: This doesn't escape special characters such as " or ,.

Comment: Also, I don't think this adds the double quotes as shown in your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
JSON.stringify(array1)
```

With

```
JSON.stringify(array1).splice(1, -1)
```

Keep in mind that you might as well re-add the square brackets on the server-side in order to parse the results correctly as JSON. If you're wanting to use custom logic to interpret the data, make sure to correctly handle escaped characters.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem, So used the following code...Hope it will suffix your requirement.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(request.getParameter("names"));

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("interests");
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){

}
```

Comment: You should post an answer that us js not java.